# Node.js debug.enable for all dependencies

Tags: node.js

```
require('debug').enable('*')
```

It works ok for my program, but it does not work for packages that use `debug` too.
For example package `needle`, how to enable debug for this package?
How to enable debug for all the packages which use `debug`?

I want to switch on/off debug in runtime, without application restarting

Answer (score 0):

```
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')
fs.readdirSync('node_modules').forEach(f => {
  try {
    const debugPackage = path.join('./node_modules', f, '/node_modules/debug')
    fs.statSync(debugPackage).isDirectory()
    require(`./${debugPackage}/node.js`).enable('*')
  }
  catch (unused) {}
})
```

As a workaround